# Is there a way to perform edit distance (Levenshtein) character by character between two string columns?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, machine-learning, edit-distance

I have two datasets: dataset1 & dataset2, which have a common column called `SAX` which is a string object.

```
dataset1=
         SAX
0    gangsyu
1    zicobgm
2    eerptow
3    cqbsynt
4    zvmqben
..       ...
475  rfikekw
476  bnbzvqx
477  rsuhgax
478  ckhloio
479  lbzujtw

480 rows × 2 columns
```

and

```
dataset2=
         SAX
0    gdmgsyu
1    zifgbgm
2    esdftow
3    cqtjgnt
4    znweben
..       ...
475  rfikekw
476  bnbzvqx
477  rsuhgax
478  ckhloio
479  lbzujtw

480 rows × 2 columns
```

I need the output to be a column which is the sum of the number of the edits/changes it takes for SAX(dataset1) to become SAX(dataset2).The variation is basically what I am considering as an "edit/change" . (Example shown below)

```
Taking the first row of SAX from dataset1 and dataset 2 and comparing.
"gangsyu" and "gdmgsyu"

First character "g" is a match, so move on.
Second character is not a match, it takes 3 edits to change "a" to "d". 
Third character is not a match, it takes 1 edit to change "n" to "m"
Rest of the characters match.
I want the column to be a sum of the edits/changes which is 3+1 = 4.(shown below)
dataset3= 
     sum_edits
0    4 (for the example shown right above)
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    0
..       ...
475  3
476  0
477  8
478  1
479  4

480 rows × 2 columns
```

Is there a function/method to accomplish this? Would appreciate it a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: Are your strings always the same length? How should the distance function behave otherwise?

Comment: yeah, strings are same length, no insertion or deletion needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that makes calculating Levenshtein distance easy ([python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/)).

If you're willing to use the library, you can simply iterate through your datasets and calculate `distance(item_dataset_1, item_dataset_2)`.

But in your example it is unclear to me why you count the change from a to d as 3 edits. It should be counted as 1 edit to calculate the Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? I'm not entirely sure

```
foo = ["gangsyu", "zicobgm", "eerptow", "cqbsynt", "zvmqben"]
bar = ["gdmgsyu", "zifgbgm", "esdftow", "cqtjgnt", "znweben"]

from collections import Counter

edits = 0

for word1, word2 in zip(foo, bar):
    x = Counter([letter for letter in word1])
    y = Counter([letter for letter in word2])
    edits += len(x - y)

# Outputs 13
print(edits)
```

Counter is great, it counts items in a list/tuple and creates a dict out of it

**EDIT** (after clarifications)

The edit change for "a" to "d" is because "d" is 3 letters after "a" in the alphabet, and 1 for "n" to "m", right? I was confused on whatever that meant

You could probably set up an alphabet index like this:

```
alpahbetindex = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3,
    "d":4,
    "e":5,
    "f":6,
    "g":7,
    "h":8,
    "i":9,
    "j":10,
    "k":11,
    "l":12,
    "m":13,
    "n":14,
    "o":15,
    "p":16,
    "q":17,
    "r":18,
    "s":19,
    "t":20,
    "u":21,
    "v":22,
    "w":23,
    "x":24,
    "y":25,
    "z":26,
}
```

Then have this nested for loop compare each letter in each word and if they're different pass the two letters to the function and the function returns the positive value difference between the two letters based on alphabet index.

```
foo = ["gangsyu", "zicobgm", "eerptow", "cqbsynt", "zvmqben"]
bar = ["gdmgsyu", "zifgbgm", "esdftow", "cqtjgnt", "znweben"]

def func(char1, char2):
    x = alpahbetindex[char1.lower()]
    y = alpahbetindex[char2.lower()]
    return max(x, y, key=float) - min(x, y, key=float)

edits = 0
for word1, word2 in zip(foo, bar):
    for i in range(7):
        if word1[i] != word2[i]:
            changes = func(word1[i], word2[i])
            edits += changes
# Outputs 128
print(edits)
```

Likely there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
"gangsyu" and "gdmgsyu"

First character "g" is a match, so move on.
Second character is not a match, it takes 3 edits to change "a" to "d". 
Third character is not a match, it takes 1 edit to change "n" to "m"
Rest of the characters match.
```

This is not [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Example), but appears to be some mutation of [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), though last does only consider if character does match or does not match.

Comment: oh sorry about that, I figured it would be a variation of Levenshtein distance. Is there a function/method to accomplish this?